# hector slam with existing map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know if there is a way to use hector_slam package starting from an existing map (generated with Hector_slam) and upgrading/expanding it.

I've been trying but without results.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59557/hector-slam-with-existing-map/) by [Buttz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3714/buttz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a request that pops up every once in a while (another example [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/47496/hector_slam-how-to-load-a-saved-map-and-perform-localization/)). It's currently not implemented, but certainly possible to add it with a little time investement (time I don't have at the moment).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Buttz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3714/buttz/) on 2013-04-01**:
Thanks for letting me know!